# powerpc-eabivle-gcc does not support e_and2i instruction

Tags: assembly, gcc, bit-manipulation, powerpc, opcode

I am using NXP's GCC 4.9 VLE compiler. I am targeting an e200z7 core. I want to disable 16th bit of the MSR register. Here is what I am using:

```
/* Disable MSR[EE] bit*/
        mfmsr   r6
        e_and2i r6,0x7fff
        mtmsr   r6
```

When I compile the .S file using powerpc_eabivle_4_9/bin/powerpc-eabivle-gcc, it gives me following error:

```
Error: unrecognized opcode: `e_and2i'
```

How to set it to 0 without the `and` instruction?

Comment: Yes. It's there in CFLAGS, LDLAGS and ASFLAGS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This really is an [XY Problem](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem). You end up asking how to replace `e_and2i r6,0x7fff` with something that doesn't use `and` instruction. The real question that should be asked is "why does `e_and2i r6,0x7fff` throw an *"unrecognized opcode"* error?

The answer is pretty simple. You are targeting the e200z7 core. This core uses Variable-Length encoding (VLE). Instructions can either be 16 bit or 32 bit in length. Instructions with prefix `se_` are 16 bit in length and `e_` are 32 bit in length. Instructions ending in a period (`.`) update the Conditional Register (*CR*).

If you review the [Variable-Length Encoding (VLE) Programming Environments Manual](http://application-notes.digchip.com/314/314-68105.pdf) you will discover that there is no 2 operand `e_and2i` instruction but there is a `e_and2i.` instruction. With VLE there isn't an `e_and2i` instruction that doesn't update *CR*. If your code doesn't rely on *CR* being preserved (likely the case) you could simply change `e_and2i` to `e_and2i.`. Your code would then look like:

```
mfmsr    r6
e_and2i. r6,0x7fff
mtmsr    r6
```

Alternatively you can use the 3 operand form `e_andi` that doesn't update CR. It would look like:

```
mfmsr    r6
e_andi   r6,r6,0x7fff
mtmsr    r6
```

`e_and2i.` and `e_andi` are encoded as instruction that are 32 bits in length, but there is a VLE instruction 16 bits in length that will do the job you want and doesn't update *CR*. That instruction is 2 operand **Bit Clear Immediate** `se_bclri`. Your code could have been written as:

```
mfmsr    r6
se_bclri r6,16          ; Clear the 16th bit (bit 0 is MSB and bit 31 is LSB)
mtmsr    r6
```

---

Related to Peter Cordes answer he suggested something like:

```
rlwinm r6,r6,0,17,15
```

This instruction can't be properly encoded as a VLE instruction. There is however the VLE equivalent:

```
e_rlwinm r6,r6,0,17,15
```

Comment: This is a much better answer than mine; I didn't know PowerPC even had a compact instruction format.  Is there a GCC option to generate code for it, which hopefully would have optimized to `se_bclri r6,16`?

Comment: @PeterCordes: The mainline GCC doesn't support VLE. There is a patched version of GCC that does support it - the one by NXP which is based on GCC 4.9. And yes, I just checked just now and your example reduces to a function that is `se_bclri r3,16` `se_blr`

Comment: @MichaelPetch Thanks for the detailed answer. I should have framed proper question.

Answer (score 1):

Update: see [@MichaelPetch's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62168988/powerpc-eabivle-gcc-does-not-support-e-and2i-instruction/62185456#62185456) for VLE (variable-length-encoding).  My answer is just a simple naive answer for generic PowerPC that's not optimal when compact 16-bit instructions are available.

If you applied the same technique with NXP's version of GCC that can produce VLE asm for you from C, [it will use `se_bclri r3, 16`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62168988/powerpc-eabivle-gcc-does-not-support-e-and2i-instruction/62185456?noredirect=1#comment109981771_62185456).

The general technique of asking a compiler is very very useful when you don't know every peephole optimization for an ISA off the top of your head.

---

As usual, ask a compiler:

```
unsigned foo(unsigned x) {
    return x &= ~(1UL << 15);
}
```

[compiles on Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/_Q5xa_) with GCC4.8.5 -O3 -mregnames

```
foo(unsigned int):
        rlwinm %r3,%r3,0,17,15
        blr
```

I think `rlwinm` is available on every PowerPC, or at least isn't particularly new or rare.  It takes a bit-range (start / end which can wrap around to leave only that one bit masked out) and a rotate count (which is zero in this case).

Comment: It should be ```rlwinm %r3,%r3,0,17,15```, no? As I want to mask 16th bit with 0.

Comment: @Nee: PowerPC counts bits from MSB=0.  IDK why IBM has to be different from everyone else and make everything more complicated, but they do.

Comment: Apologies, but I still could not understand this. I am a beginner. Yes, it counts from MSB 0. So, we need 1s starting from bit 17 and it will wrap around to bit 15, leaving bit 16 to 0. I referred visuals from https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20180810-00/?p=99465 .

Comment: @Nee: Oh, sorry, I did misread the question.  Updated, `1<<16` was the 17th bit (from the bottom like a normal person).  After opening a godbolt tab, I misremember it as bit #16, not the 16th bit, and didn't check that against the mask in the question.

Comment: Thanks, this is really helpful. I have stuck at this issue since yesterday.

Comment: One problem though is that the godbolt compilers don't include one of the GCC variants (patched) that support VLE.

Comment: @MichaelPetch: I guess that makes some sense, but bit-order within a register is separate from byte order in memory.  Also, most other big-endian and bi-endian processors like MIPS don't do that in their documentation or bit-numbering for bitfield instructions.  I think it's more of an IBM thing than a big-endian thing, although IBM's other CPUs (S/360) are also big-endian.  But IBM isn't the only company that makes big-endian CPUs; I think MSB-first bit numbering is much rarer than big-endianness.

Comment: I really meant to say that with these processors but numbering is reverse order from what you'd normally expect. Bit 0 is MSB and Bit 31 is LSB. Bit 16 happens to be what we'd normally think as bit 15 had we numbered in the opposite direction.

Comment: @MichaelPetch: Oh, yes I knew about IBM's bit-numbering convention (and so did the OP).  That wasn't the source of confusion in the first 2 comments, just a mixup on my part between "16th bit" and `1<<16`, forgetting what the OP had said and what AND mask they used.  I was assuming that the OP was counting bits from the bottom of the register (LSB=0) instead of following IBM's bit-numbering convention, and it does seem that's what they actually wanted.  Anyway, I think everyone's on the same page about this now.